# Prove for any functions $g_1,g_2:Y\rightarrow A$, if $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f$, then $g_1=g_2$ then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Show that $f$ is surjective if and only if for any set $A$ and any functions $g_1,g_2:Y\rightarrow A$, if $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f$, then $g_1=g_2$.

$(\implies)$
From the definition of surjective function, we know that, every element of the function's codomain is the image of at least one element of its domain. That is, for every $y$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

$$
\begin{align}
\forall y\in Y &\implies \exists x\in X:f(x)=y\\
&\implies g_1(y)=g_1(f(x))=g_2(f(x))=g_2(y)
\end{align}
$$
Hence, $g_1=g_2$ for all $y\in Y$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$

Now, given that,
$$
\begin{align}
g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f 
\end{align}
$$
I can't use $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f \implies f = g_1^{-1}\circ g_2\circ f$, as I don't know the inverse exist and how could I conclude surjective of $f$. How to prove the only if part? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not surjective, let $Z$ be the range of $f$ (that is, $Z=f(X)$). Take $A=\{0,1\}$, $g_1$ is the null function and$$g_2(x)=\chi_Z(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in Z\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f$, but $g_1\ne g_2$.